# Vbscript proxy settings

Tags: windows, proxy, scripting

I'm trying to create a script that allows the user to choose which proxy settings want to use among several possible. The changes are applied correctly but takes about 20 or 30 seconds to appear at the proxy settings of Internet Explorer.
My scripts are called from a .bat process running as administrator. Any idea?

Comment: Hello and welcome to serverfault. Please take the time to read your question again and ask yourself if someone knowing nothing about your situation has all the element to start troubleshooting. Thereafter, please adds the (numerous) missing details and you might get an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, @Stephane you're right. First I'll start by scripts that I am using:

Proxy.bat

```
@echo off
rem Programa: cambioProxy.bat

set ruta=%0
cd %ruta:~0,-16% 

:Menu
  cls
  echo CAMBIO DE SCRIPTS
  echo -------------------------
  echo.
  echo A. Proxy proxy1
  echo B. Proxy proxy2
  echo S. Salir
  echo.

  choice /C abs /n /T 15 /D S /M "Seleccione Proxy "
  if errorlevel 3 goto Salir
  if errorlevel 2 goto proxy2
  if errorlevel 1 goto proxy1
  if errorlevel 0 goto Menu

:proxy1
    takeown /F %ruta:~0,-16%\proxy1.vbs
    proxy1.vbs
    echo Cambio de Proxy Realizado a proxy1
  goto Menu
:proxy2
    takeown /F %ruta:~0,-16%\proxy2.vbs
    proxy2.vbs
    echo Cambio de Proxy Realizado a proxy2
  goto Menu
:Salir
  echo.
```

These are the scripts. Are identical, except for the server and port, then I'll change exceptions

Proxy1.vbs

```
dim strProxyServer 

' define el proxy y el puerto si es necesario
strProxyServer = "proxy1:8080"

' ubicacion en la registry
dim strRegPath
strRegPath = "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\"
Set oWshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

' modifica las entradas en el registro
Call oWshShell.RegWrite(strRegPath & "ProxyEnable", "00000001", "REG_DWORD")
Call oWshShell.RegWrite(strRegPath & "ProxyOverride", "localhost;webmail.*;", "REG_SZ")
Call oWshShell.RegWrite(strRegPath & "ProxyServer", strProxyServer, "REG_SZ")
Call oWshShell.RegWrite(strRegPath & "AutoConfigURL", "", "REG_SZ")

' notificacion
Msgbox "Proxy setting enabled. " & VbCrLf & "Server - " & strProxyServer
' destroy    
Set oWshShell = Nothing
```

Proxy2.vbs

```
dim strProxyServer 

' define el proxy y el puerto si es necesario
strProxyServer = "proxy2:80"

' ubicacion en la registry
dim strRegPath
strRegPath = "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\"
Set oWshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

' modifica las entradas en el registro
Call oWshShell.RegWrite(strRegPath & "ProxyEnable", "00000001", "REG_DWORD")
Call oWshShell.RegWrite(strRegPath & "ProxyOverride", "localhost;", "REG_SZ")
Call oWshShell.RegWrite(strRegPath & "ProxyServer", strProxyServer, "REG_SZ")
Call oWshShell.RegWrite(strRegPath & "AutoConfigURL", "", "REG_SZ")

' notificacion
Msgbox "Proxy setting enabled. " & VbCrLf & "Server - " & strProxyServer
' destroy    
Set oWshShell = Nothing
```

My SO is Windows 7 Professional.Don't know if there's anything else I can add